# Different NSIS UAC Plugin

Tags: uac, nsis

I made an NSIS installer that uses a UAC plugin awhile back.  Now I am trying to build this installer on a new (Windows 7) machine.

I have installed NSIS, and [this UAC plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in), but when I try to compile my script, I get this error:

> Invalid command: ${UAC.I.Elevate.AdminOnly}

At that point, I tried the older version of the UAC plugin on that same web page, but received the same error.

Can you help me identify which UAC plugin uses `${UAC.I.Elevate.AdminOnly}`?  I believe I have downloaded the wrong UAC plugin (or wrong version), but I cannot find the correct one to use.

Google has been of little help on this one.  I've stumbled through many pages, and can't find what I am looking for, but plenty of examples of people using it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an old macro, you would have to go back to v0.0.x ([v0.0.11d](http://stashbox.org/560965/UAC%20v0.0.11d.zip) is probably the last version that supports it)